# How to display comma separated descriptions based on comma separated values in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am new to Oracle technology. Earlier I posted 2 posts for the same issue due to lack of understanding the requirement.

Table 1:

```
MSGID
-----
1,2,3
2,3
4
null
null
```

Table 2:

```
MID   MSGDESC
----  -------
1     ONE
2     TWO
3     THREE
4     FOUR
```

Expected output:

```
XCOL     DESC
-----    -----
1,2,3    ONE,TWO,THREE
2,3      TWO,THREE
4        FOUR
```

I am not able to fulfil this requirement. Please provide me one solution.

Note: tables don't have any unique or primary key values. Table 1 has 5000 records and table 2 only has 80 records with descriptions.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a two step process; figure out how to treat the CSV IDs in table 1 as individual rows (search here for ways to do that), and then join the results of that to table 2.

Comment: hi as per your suggestion i did the same task before posting this one .but i am not able to get this. could you eloberate it or could you post the code how do i get this result. this is very urgent requirement. please provide me step by step process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Table1 (MSGID varchar2(100));

insert into Table1 values ('1,2,3');
insert into Table1 values ('2,3');
insert into Table1 values ('4');
insert into Table1 values (null);
insert into Table1 values (null);

create table Table2 (MID varchar2(100), MSGDESC varchar2(100));

insert into Table2 values ('1','ONE');
insert into Table2 values ('2','TWO');
insert into Table2 values ('3','THREE');
insert into Table2 values ('4','FOUR');
```

---

```
select
  msgid as xcol, 
  "DESC", 
  col1, col2, ..., col12
from
  Table1
  left join (
    select
       msgid,
       wm_concat(msgdesc) as "DESC"
    from
       (
          select
             msgid,
             msgdesc
          from
             (select distinct msgid from Table1 where ...)
             cross join (
                select level as occ from dual connect by level <= 100)
             )
             left join Table2
                on mid = regexp_substr(msgid, '[^,]+', 1, occ)
          where
             occ <= regexp_count(msgid, ',') + 1
          order by msgid, occ
       )
    group by msgid
  ) using (msgid)
```

Comment: hi Egor , thank you for you reply , wm_concat is valid in oracle 10g or not?

Comment: many thanks for your reply.i have to use 12 mandatory columns in my select statement , shall use those colum names in the above query like select xcol,col1,col2...desc from table1 and table2. and i have to use the above coding in 8 table joins in my actual requirement.

Comment: @Prasad - You should replace `Table1` in subquery with `select msgid from Table1 where ...` and join the whole query result (xcol, desc) with your Table1 to get other columns.

Comment: if u don't mine ,all the columns from table-1 only if you dont mine could you tell me how do i use all 12 columns from table 1  in the above query completely table 2 is used only for description data only.

Comment: thanks Egor , you are my real god , it is throwing the error in where ...,

Comment: @Prasad - you should insert your custom conditions instead of `where ...` or simply remove it.

Comment: Hi Egor , i am getting the missing expression error after eliminating  the colq..col12 and where.. . kindly check it once and have you tested this